# Where can I obtain research material on the synthesis of polypyrrole?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, polymers, reference-request

I'm studying Chemistry at A-level and a large part of the course is a researcher paper that takes most of the year.

Conductive polymers interest me. I'm struggling to find any surfeited researcher on the synthesis of polypyrrole. I not sure if I need to buy a paper or another course of action would be more suitable.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Hi Jacob, the trouble when you're first starting out is knowing where to look! Any book on conducting polymers should have the answer, but also look up how you might make bipyrrole. This can then be extended to a polymeric approach. My undergraduate dissertation was on conducting polymers and LED's. It might take me a while, but I can dig out a good reference text as there were no online references when I wrote it!

Comment: Thank you! Any text references would be extremely useful. I'm planning on making the polypyrrole electrochemically.